# Comme appeler quelqu'un qui aime les langues ?

Tags: choix-de-mot

Comment appeler quelqu'un qui aime apprendre et parler différents langues ?
En anglais il y a l'expression "language enthusiast" ou le mot (rare) "linguaphile" mais je ne connais pas d'équivalent en français.

Remarque: "polyglotte" est trop prétentieux pour ce que je cherche, disons que "matheux" est à "mathématicien" ce que le mot/l'expression que je cherche est à "polyglotte".

Comment: Ce n'est pas que polyglotte soit prétentieux, c'est que ça n'a rien à voir. Un polyglotte est peut-être « amateur/passioné » de langues mais le terme lui-même désigne quelqu'un qui parle plusieurs langues. Par ailleurs un matheux n'est pas un *maths enthusiast*, c'est avant tout quelqu'un qui est  [fort en maths](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/matheux). On peut être fort sans aimer particulièrement.

Comment: A Paris, il y a une association: Association Langophile.

Comment: linguaphile is a language lover, but does not imply speaking necessarily.

Answer (score 2):

Il existe en français un mot similaire au terme anglais.

> ([Witionnaire](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/linguophile)) **linguophile** \lɛ̃.ɡɥɔ.fil\ masculin et féminin identiques
> (Rare)
> Personne qui aime les langues et les mots.

Answer (score 1):

*Enthusiast* n'est pas un terme réservé à un amateur de langues.
*A crossword enthusiast* est un amateur/un passionné de mots croisés. *A music enthusiast* est un (fervent) amateur de musique/un passionné de musique. [*A lighthouse enthusiast*](https://www.ourcommons.ca/DocumentViewer/en/39-2/house/sitting-64/hansard) est [un passionné des phares](https://www.noscommunes.ca/DocumentViewer/fr/39-2/chambre/seance-64/debats). [*A book enthusiast*](https://www.ourcommons.ca/DocumentViewer/en/38-1/house/sitting-154/hansard) est un [*passionné du livre*](https://www.noscommunes.ca/DocumentViewer/fr/38-1/chambre/seance-154/debats), etc. (ces deux dernières traductions sont des traductions officielles québécoises).

Et un *language enthusiast* est un passionné de langues.

> Passionné de langues depuis mon plus jeune âge, j'ai toujours aimé apprendre les langues et faire des activités en lien avec ces dernières. [→](https://www.codeur.com/-cedraman)

> Passionné de langues, Jean-Pierre Minaudier possède 1 163 livres de grammaires de 864 idiomes différents. [→](https://www.festivalvo-vf.com/invite-e-s-2021-jean-pierre-minaudier/)

> Vous êtes passionnée, passionné de langues et littérature ? [→](https://www.occitanetudesmetiers.com/l-occitan-pourquoi.htm)

> L’un des auteurs de ce rapport, passionné de langues, qui a appris le français dans des livres à partir de 11 ans et qui vit en France depuis trente-neuf ans déjà, en fournit un exemple vivant. [→](https://www.education.gouv.fr/media/15155/download)

Par ailleurs il existe le mot français [linguophile](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/linguophile), équivalent de l'anglais *linguaphile*, mais peu employé, beaucoup moins que « amateur de »  ou « passionné de ».